# Convolution of scaled variable

Tags: convolution

A rather simple question...

Is the following true?

$$f * f(\frac{x}{a}) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(u)f(\frac{x}{a}-u)du$$

Or is it

$$f * f(\frac{x}{a}) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(\frac{u}{a})f(\frac{x}{a}-u)du$$

or something else...?

Comment: The answer is rather obvious, will answer it myself in a little while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(u)f(\frac{x}{a}-u)du = \int_\mathbb{R} f(\frac{u}{a})f(\frac{x}{a}-\frac{u}{a})du$$

since we're integrating over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Although this doesn't take care of the potential scaling, $du$ or $du/a$...???

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g(x)=f(\frac{x}{a})$

\begin{align}
f*f(\frac{x}{a})&=f(x)*g(x)\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}f(u)g(x-u)du\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}f(u)f(\frac{x-u}{a})du\\
\end{align}

And for the other possibility

\begin{align}
f*f(\frac{x}{a})&=f(x)*g(x)\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x-u)g(u)du\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x-u)f(\frac{u}{a})du\\
\end{align}

Therefore, the statements in the question are not true.